# stop google-chromebook from repeatedly opening "Fix Issues with Business Messages" support page

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

I have a ~4 year old Google Model C0A Chromebook that **repeatedly** opens an error message in a new window, especially when using gmail composer or linkedin chat. It seems to be spontaneous and can happen without touching the keyboard or mouse, provided a site like gmail or linkedin is open.  This disrupts work to the extent that, while writing this question, I was switched to 6+ identical windows that I have to switch back from and close.

The URL it opens is:

https://support.google.com/messages?p=bhm

this links to:

https://support.google.com/messages/answer/9744268?visit_id=638334215522733759-2541759264&p=bhm&rd=1#zippy=

These are entitled "Fix issues with Business Messages" and offers 3 alternatives:

- Turn off private browsing  [*but I'm in a regular window not an incognito window*]
- Fix Google Play Services [*haven't tried this one.  have tried updating chrome OS*]
- Enable Premium SMS [*I don't need or want this*]

Visiting `about:` yields:

```
Google Chrome   118.0.5993.86 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
Revision    d9a55e23605b9c433d369a305c71114843ec754d-refs/branch-heads/5993@{#1287}
Platform    15604.45.0 (Official Build) stable-channel eve
Firmware Version    Google_Eve.9584.230.0
Customization ID    GOOGLE-EVE
ARC 10919957 SDK Version: 30
JavaScript  V8 11.8.172.15
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 14541.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

How do I stop google-chromebook from repeatedly opening this seemingly irrelevant message?

Comment: This message might be related to Instagram - do you have it installed?

Comment: @harrymc instagram is not installed as an app